# Django 1.9 CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a problem with CSRF. I know must use: {% csrf_token %} but the problem is the same.

This my form:

```
<form action="." method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
    .......
</form>
```

views.py:

Try 1:

```
def registro(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hola')
```

Try 2:

```
def registro(request):
    c={}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('registro.html',c)
```

Try 3:

```
def registro(request):
    c={}
    return render(request,'nuevavista.html',c)
```

complete views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, HttpResponse, render,RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Articulo
from django.template import RequestContext

# Create your views here.


#Nueva vista

def nuevavista(request):
    #return render_to_response(request,'nuevavista.html')
    #return render(request,'blog/nuevavista.html')
    #return HttpResponse('Nueva web')
    return render_to_response(request,'nuevavista.html')
    #return render_to_response('nuevavista.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 

def registro(request):
    #if request.method=='POST':
    c={}
    #c.update(csrf(request))
    #return render_to_response('registro.html',c)
    #return    render(request,'registro.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    #return HttpResponse('Hola')
    return render(request,'nuevavista.html',c)

def home(request):
    articulos = Articulo.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'articulos':articulos})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    #url de nueva vista
    url(r'^nuevavista','blog.views.nuevavista',name="nuevavista"),
    url(r'^registro','blog.views.registro',name="registro"),


    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', 'blog.views.home',name='home'),
]
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Mi pagina</title>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/estilo.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Mi primera pagina </p>

    {% for articulo in articulos %}
    <h1> <a href="{% url 'blog.views.nuevavista' %}" >Titulo   {{articulo.titulo}}</a></h1>
    <p>Autor {{articulo.autor}}</p>
    <p>Texto del articulo {{articulo.texto}}</p>
    <p>Fecha {{articulo.fecha}} </p>
    {% endfor %}


    <p>Formulario</p>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!--<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars'/>-->
        <label> Nombre: </label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" maxlength="100">
        <input type="submit" value="envíar">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

registro.html:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Mi pagina</title>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/estilo.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Registro </p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alasdair I edit my question, tell me if you need something more.

Comment: Is your action really `action="."`?

Comment: @Lian what you suggest?

Comment: Please show the entire template, your urls.py, and the url you are accessing the form on.

Comment: @Alasdair I edit the question and put what you say. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `{% csrf_token %}` tag to work, you must ensure that the template is rendered with the request object (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)).

The easiest way to do this is to use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut instead of [`render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response). The `render_to_response` method is not recommended, and is likely to be removed from Django in future.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def registro(request):
    c = {}  
    # put any other context you need in c
    # no need for c.update(csrf(request)) because we're using render    
    return render(request, 'registro.html', c)
```

You need to update any views that use csrf_token in their templates. In this case, you haven't updated the `home` view that renders the form in the `index.html` template.

```
def home(request):
    articulos = Articulo.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'articulos':articulos})
```

Comment: Still the same situtation.

Comment: You are still using `render_to_response` in your other views, which is causing the problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: I see.. you say  "home" i understand know, thanks a lot.